# Rebind digits for normal mode in evil

Tags: emacs, text-editor, key-bindings, evil-mode

Is it possible to rebind digits. That, for example, "5" is "$", and "%" is "5"?

In [evil-maps.el](https://github.com/emacsmirror/evil/blob/master/evil-maps.el) digits are defined like this.

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "1" 'digit-argument)
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "2" 'digit-argument)
...
```

I tried the answer of @ChillarAnand

```
(add-hook 'evil-mode-hook 'evil-mode-bindings)

(defun evil-mode-bindings ()
  "Bind symbols to digits."
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "%") "5")
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "*") "8")
  )
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "5" 'evil-beginning-of-line)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "8" 'evil-end-of-line)
```

But `Shift-5` still does not behave like `5`, the same is true for `8`.
Is it possible to fix it for the config above?

The same stands for @tarblet solution.

What I use as a test is a sequence `Shift-5`, `G`.

Comment: So you want `%` to map to `digit-argument` with a value of 5?

Comment: Yes, I think so. That when I press `Shift-5` the editor behave like I pressed `5` in the default configuration.

Comment: Forgot to add to the snippet.

Comment: i think your  key bindings are getting  modified  after this step, can you run `C-h k Shift-5` & `C-h k G` and make sure they are binded to `evil-beginning-of-line` &  `evil-goto-line &optional COUNT` respectively?

Comment: @user14416 What seems to be the problem with my solution?  Did you test the updated version (motion state → normal state)?

Answer (score 2):

Quite a hacky solution, but it should do what you want:

```
(defun capslock-digit-argument-fn (digit)
  `(lambda (arg)
     (interactive "P")
     (setq last-command-event (+ ,digit ?0))
     (digit-argument arg)))

(define-key evil-motion-state-map "!" (capslock-digit-argument-fn 1))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "@" (capslock-digit-argument-fn 2))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "#" (capslock-digit-argument-fn 3))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "$" (capslock-digit-argument-fn 4))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "%" (capslock-digit-argument-fn 5))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "^" (capslock-digit-argument-fn 6))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "&" (capslock-digit-argument-fn 7))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "*" (capslock-digit-argument-fn 8))
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "(" (capslock-digit-argument-fn 9))
```

It rebinds the variable which `digit-argument` looks at when trying to figure out which key was pressed. If you don't mind `)` not behaving exactly like `0` (no jumping to beginning of line, only working as digit arg) you could set it as well.

Comment: You solution does not work for example for sequend of `Shift-5`, `G`.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that you asked for normal-mode, not just motion mode.  Please try replacing `evil-motion-state-map` with `evil-normal-state-map` in above code.

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse, anything is possible in emacs :)

Add this piece of code to you config.

```
(add-hook 'evil-mode-hook 'evil-mode-bindings)

(defun evil-mode-bindings ()
  "Bind symbols to digits."
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "!") (kbd "1"))
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "@") (kbd "2"))
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "#") (kbd "3"))
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "$") (kbd "4"))
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "%") (kbd "5"))
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "^") (kbd "6"))
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "&") (kbd "7"))
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "*") (kbd "8"))
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "(") (kbd "9"))
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd ")") (kbd "0")))
```

Whenever You enter evil mode, `evil-mode-hook` runs `evil-mode-bindings` function. This function binds, symbols to corresponding digits.

**Update:**

As @npostavs mentioned, You can also use this

```
(add-hook 'evil-mode-hook 'evil-mode-bindings)

(defun evil-mode-bindings ()
  "Bind symbols to digits."
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "!") "1")
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "@") "2")
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "#") "3")
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "$") "4")
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "%") "5")
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "^") "6")
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "&") "7")
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "*") "8")
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd "(") "9")
  (define-key key-translation-map (kbd ")") "0"))
```

Comment: @npostavs thanks. previous code was not working properly. updated code.

Comment: @npostavs gotcha. updated  answer as per  your comments. thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you guys. Could you look at the updated question?

Comment: "you can't put any keybinding in the last position, only simple strings." - oops, actually I got confused, `key-translation-map` is special, you actually *can* put any keybinding as the definition.

Comment: Sorry I dont get you.